# Nginx and github for website

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, nginx

I just setup an EC2 server with nginx/php/mysql/ruby-rails.

I was wondering if there was a way to use my github repo and clone it onto the web server every time I make a commit. some of the files are php and others are ruby.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Comment: @spedsal: make it an answer, it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/